# how to sum double numbers in bash

Tags: bash, arithmetic-expressions

I want to do a sum in bash, but numbers are with dot and not with comma (Ex: 1.2333)

I tried to do this script

```
#!/bin/bash 
somma=0 
n=0 
tempo=0
val=0
while read -r val1 val2 
do 
  somma=$((somma += val1))
  tempo=$(echo $tempo += $val2 | bc) 
  n=$((n +=+1)) 
done < "ret.txt" 
echo $tempo
```

but I got this error:

```
 (standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Comment: Why not use a tool that supports floating point numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
somma=0
n=0
tempo=0
val=0
while read -r val1 val2; do
    ((somma += val1))
    tempo=$(bc <<< "$tempo + $val2")
    ((n++))
done < "ret.txt"
echo "$tempo"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '
    {sum1 += $1; sum2 += $2} 
    END {print "somma=" sum1; print "tempo=" sum2}
' filename
```

If you need those values in your bash script, `eval` the output of that awk command, or:

```
read somma tempo < <(
    awk '{sum1 += $1; sum2 += $2} END {print sum1, sum2}' filename
)
```